# Can anyone help me by translating the characters in this image?

Tags: translation, characters, character-identification, traditional-characters, seal

These characters located at the bottom right corner of my silk painting, consist of a seal (which I believe could be the artist's chop) and cursive script located above the seal.
I used filters to enhance due to the fading. The painting was found folded inside an old Hiroshima newspaper dated late 1940s.[image]

Comment: I mentioned that the image was faded due to aging.  Only knowledgeable responders (not fault finders) need reply.

Comment: I feel it is Japanese.